# not functioning in while($row->$statement->fetch()) using php PDO

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop

```
if(isset($_POST['btnLogin']))
{
$username = $_POST['txtusername'];
$pass_word = $_POST['txtpassword'];
$hashed_password = crypt(sha1($pass_word));


$sqlQuery  = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password" ;
$statement = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute(array(':username' =>$user , ':password'=>$hashed_password));

while($row->$statement->fetch())
{
    $id       = $row['id'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $password = $row['password'];

    if(strcmp('$password', '$hashed_password') == 0)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log("Sucess");</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log("Failed");</script>";
    }

}

}
```

**In here I am implementing the Sign in a page using PHP PDO codes.
I have no previous experience in using PHP PDO.I do the Sign up page without any errors but unfortunately program is not execute after**

> *while($row->$statement->fetch())*

here are the HTML codes

```
<section>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="login-form">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <form id="login-form" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="txtusername" placeholder="Username" data-validation="required">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="password" name="txtpassword" placeholder="Password" data-validation="required">
            </div>
                <input type="submit" name="btnLogin" value="Login">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**PHP VERSION : 5.3.8**

Please give any suggestion to me for solve it

Comment: That's because your `while($row->$statement` should be `while($row=$statement`.

Comment: Voted this as a typographical error.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i did change which is you mentioned above but it stil not working

Comment: Enable error reporting and error handling on the query http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - The password should have also been saved as the same hash, but I don't know why you are using what you're using now, why not use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead? While making sure the password column is long enough to hold the hash.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner My php version not supported these function these functions working on 5.7 above i think. therefore i didn't use these functions.i  tried some console output below and above of the while($row = $statement->fetch()) above console log was printed but below console log was not printed.

Comment: Ah yeah, I forget about that; good point.

Comment: Please dont amend the question. It makes the answers/comment look ridiculous

Comment: `password_hash()` has been available since PHP 5.5. If it's not available, that means you are wanting to handle sensitive user data with code that has been EOL for at least 5 years? Bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. If it doesn't work, [wrap your query in this](https://gist.github.com/nyl2k8/ed728c3ec298339fdd0f736386332519) and turn error reporting on.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnLogin']))
{
$username = $_POST['txtusername'];
$pass_word = $_POST['txtpassword'];
$hashed_password = crypt(sha1($pass_word));


$sqlQuery  = "SELECT * from users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password" ;
$statement = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute(array(':username' =>$user , ':password'=>$hashed_password));

while($row = $statement->fetch_object())
{
    $id       = $row->id;
    $username = $row->username;
    $password = $row->password;

    if(strcmp('$password', '$hashed_password') == 0)
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">console.log("Success");</script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">console.log("Failed");</script>';
    }

}
```

}